# Netgear UTM9S port forwarding causing drop off

Tags: firewall, troubleshooting, internet

Our company just installed a Netgear UTM9S and I've been trying to get our server visible to the outside world.

I've gone into firewall settings and set up a new rule that states all incoming HTTP traffic be forwarded onto 192.168.1.82, port 8881.

For a while the server is visible when visiting the building IP address from both on and off the network, but for some reason our internet will cut off after about 10 minutes and the firewall admin panel is not available. The only thing that can be done is to power cycle the firewall and delete the rule.

I'm pretty new to networking in general, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you provided no further explanation, I will take a shot in the wild: your router has it's own administrative interface on the same port you are trying to redirect/forward.

Normally when someone on the internet types into his/her browser your address, e.g. `youraddress.org` he or she would be directed at your UTM appliance's administrative interface (which may even be blocked from the WAN ports, so they would see nothing).

If you are forwarding :

- WAN port 8881 to LAN address 192.168.1.82 port 8881
- or WAN port 8881 to LAN address 192.168.1.82 port 80

then you are doing the right thing, but internet users should type in their browsers `youraddress.org:8881`. In this case I can't help you any further.

If by any chance you are forwarding WAN port 80 to LAN 192.168.1.82 port 8881 then this won't work. Your UTM might even get stuck from this, as you are saying it does, I don't know. You would first have to make your UTM's administrative interface to listen on some other port than 80. Unfortunately I could not find any option in UTM9S user's manual that would allow to do that.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. Looks like there is no (easy) way to achieve what I'm trying to do with this hardware.